# What does it mean for a polynomial to have an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm looking at my notes from my linear algebra lecture. It states

...

$
\forall P \in K[t]:$

$$
P \, is \, invertible \, \iff deg(P)=0 \iff P \in K^*
$$

...

---

I find this quite confusing. What does exactly mean for a polynomial to be "invertible" and why is this particularly important? Also; given that $K[t]$ is a field, does it not follow that *all* elements in K have an inverse (otherwise it would not be a field). And lastly, what does $K^*$ stand for?

I tried looking for information about this online but did not manage to find an answer to this exact problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means has a multiplicative inverse, so there is some other polynomial $Q$ such that $PQ = 1$. $K[t]$ is not a field. $K^{\ast}$ is the group of invertible elements of $K$, in this context regarded as the nonzero constant polynomials in $K[t]$.

Comment: The inverse of a polynomial is simply the function reflected across $y=x$.

Comment: @Frank  No thats not what we are discussing in this context. You are talking about the set theoretical inverse of the function associated to the polynomial. Here we consider the inverse of a polynomial in the ring $k[x]$, which is very different.

Comment: @user2520938 Cool, I learned something new...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inverse to $p(x)\in k[x]$ is an element $q(x)\in k[x]$ such that $p(x)q(x)=1\in k[x]$. We know that (if $k$ is a domain, so in particular for fields)
$$deg(p(x)q(x))=deg(p(x))+deg(q(x))$$
and that
$$deg(1)=0$$
it follows that
$$deg(p(x))=deg(q(x))=0$$
i.e. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are constant polynomial, which are identified with $k\hookrightarrow k[x]$.